# Tak - Do you still win, if in creating your road, you also created a road for the other player?

Tags: tak

Do you still win, if in creating your road, you also created a road for the other player?

Answer (score 6):

From the [rules for Tak](https://cheapass.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/TakWebRules.pdf) on Cheapass Games' website (page 2):

> ***Double Road:*** If a player creates a winning road for both players in the same move, then the *active  player* is the winner.

If you create a road win for both players on your turn, you still win the game.